# Why the output of this cpp code is like this?

Tags: c++

I am beginner in c++ programing
I got this question in my university exams and have no idea why the output is like that, the question goes like this
What is the output of the following code?

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
inline float square(float y){
  return y*y;
}
void main( ){
  float a = 0.5,b = 0.5, c, d; 
  c = SQUARE(++a);
  d = square(++b);
}
```

The question itself does not have any cin or cout statement to display any output in the console screen
so here is altered code

```
#include<iostream>
#define SQUARE(x)x*x
using namespace std;
inline float square(float y){
  return y*y;
}
int main(){
  float a = 0.5,b=0.5,c,d;
  c=SQUARE(++a);
  d = square(++b);
  cout<<c<<endl<<d;
}
```

And the output for the above code is
6.25
2.25
why the output isn't is 2.25 and 2.25 instead it is 6.25 and 1.25?

Comment: macros `define` is just string replacement before compilation, so actual code is `c=++a * ++a;`

Comment: Why would you expect console output, for never outputting anything??

Comment: Do you know what `#define` does? If not, I would go read a C++ tutorial. They reason they produce different values is they do *very* different things. If they did the same thing, you would not have both `#define` and regular functions in the same language.

Comment: _"I tried asking chat gpt as well but it does not give me quite clear explanation."_ I have no idea why you should expect something there? You do know what ChatGPT actually is??

Comment: There is a reason macros are not recommended. Whenever you can you should use a (template) function.

Comment: Change `#define SQUARE(x)x*x` to `#define SQUARE(x) [](auto xx){ return xx*xx; }(x)` and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I like macros:  SQUARE("circle").  If this were an inline function, you'd get an error early on.

Answer (score 0):

On preprocessing, the macros (created using `#define`) are replaced with the expressions they define.

- `SQUARE(1+2)` becomes `1+2*1+2` which is not what you want.
- `SQUARE(++a)` becomes `++a*++a` which is also not what you want.

The first situation can be solved by using parentheses in the definition of `SQUARE`:

```c
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
```

The second cannot be solved but there are alternatives:

- separate the increment from the usage of `SQUARE()`:

  ```c
  a++;
  c = SQUARE(a)`;
  ```
- transform `SQUARE()` into a function then you can use it as `SQUARE(++a)` to get the desired outcome.